# What is the \Object in function() {\Object $object} in function parameters

Tags: php, oop

I recall having seen this syntax before, and it seems valid as well.

```
function myFunction(\Object $object) { }
```

While I vaguely recall it to be just a helpful naming scheme for an otherwise dynamically-typed variable, I could not find (or rather not knowing what to search for) any reference to this kind of syntax.

Does anyone know better, and also any best practices regarding this syntax, if it is valid?

Comment: type hinting with namespaces. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi So it seems! I just tried out the autocomplete in my IDE and a whole new world has opened to me. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I don't know, this is really just a matter of syntax. You could write your own answer with some extra info and maybe some links to the manual and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash in this case is addressing the *global* namespace - classes and functions are placed there when they don't have a namespace definition. See also the [manual section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I also didn't know about it being global.